# Minecraft craftbukkit.jar Could Not Reserve Enough Space for Object Heap

Tags: memory, java, minecraft

So I started running CraftBukkit servers on my computer years ago. Now when I started up my computer today and tried to run the servers, it wasn't working. It had worked a month ago or so, but now it just stopped working with no explination. This is what the error said when i tried to start the server:

C:\Users\MyPrivate\Information\MinecraftServer>java -Xm x3G -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap

Hear are the specs for my PC, and any help would be greatly appreciated:

Processer: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U @ 2.00GHz 2.60 GHz Windows 8.1 Ram 8 GB 7.15 Usable 64 bit Operating System, x64-based processer Maker: Asus

Again, the servers were working as a month ago. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Try this `java -Xmx512m x3G -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true` its saying that it does not have 3MB of space for the Object Heap. -Xmx512m will fix the issue or at least should let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - `3145728KB` is actually `3.14 GB` not `3 MB`.  Your command wouldn't solve the author's problem since it would reduce the heap to 512MB.  I suspect the problem is a 32-bit vs 64-bit Java problem.  Adding `-d64` to the author's original attempt should solve the problem.

Comment: `java -Xmx4G -d64 -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true` is the correct command you should use.  Your heap file is larger then 3GB at this point, why it worked a month ago, is because the heap file was smaller then 3GB.

Comment: thank you @Ramhound I understand that a little more know. and I miss cacluated that thanks for pointing that out.